# How to display/hide data validation input message in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I've applied input messages to the cells:

[image]

For example if a cell is clicked then a message is displayed mentioning the cell. The problem is once the message is displayed, it does not hide unless another cell is selected. Even if I scroll the mouse the message remains on the screen:

[image]

You can see in the image that I've scrolled down the mouse but since I didn't click anywhere else so you can see the input message.

What I want to do is that the message is displayed for a couple of seconds and then it hides. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Data validation is doing exactly what it is supposed to. The use of a comment in the cell may be a better solution. When using a comment, it displays when the mouse is near the upper right corner of the cell, then goes away after a few seconds.

[image]

You can insert a comment by right clicking the cell and choosing `Insert comment` from the context menu. You will then be prompted to add text.